# data in router is undefined in angular 7

Tags: angular7-router

I have a route like below:

{ path: 'contact-us', component: ContactUsComponent , data: {isPrivate: false}},

When I try to get the above **isPrivate** value on ngOnInit() of **ContactUsComponent.ts**, it gives undefined:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
..
ngOnInit() {
 this._private = this.route.snapshot.data['isPrivate'];
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try getting the property right in the constructor:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this._private = this.route.snapshot.data['isPrivate'];
}
```

Comment: don't do this use ngOnInit instead.

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
constructor(router:Router, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    router.events
      .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .forEach(e => {
        this.title = route.root.firstChild.snapshot.data['PageName'];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:-

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
OnInit() {
  this.route.data.subscribe(private => this._private = private);
}
```